# populate field based on max of another field in a table join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, max

I've tried this a few different ways, but have yet to succeed.

I'm trying to join `tbl1` and `tbl2` to show the status in `tbl1` and status from `tbl2` where `tbl1.wonum = tbl2.wonum` and the record with `max(change_date)`.

Can anyone help with this?

**Contents of `TBL1`:**

```
 WONUM | STATUS
---------------
   1   | text
   2   | text
   3   | text
   4   | text
```

**Contents of `TBL2`:**

```
 WONUM | STATUS | CHANGEDATE
-----------------------------
   1   | text1  |   28-Oct
   1   | text2  |   25-Oct
   1   | text3  |   31-Oct
   1   | text4  |    1-Oct
   2   | text3  |   28-Oct
   2   | text3  |   25-Oct
   2   | text3  |   31-Oct
   3   | text3  |    1-Oct
   3   | text3  |    1-Oct
   4   | text3  |   25-Oct
   4   | text3  |    1-Oct
```

Comment: You should include your desire output.

Comment: Sorry, a simple report with the following:
tbl1.wonum, tbl1.status, tbl2.status

Comment: Rick but what data? You mention a `max()` but isnt clear how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd658/8)**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM (
      SELECT 
          T1."WONUM", T1."STATUS", T2."STATUS", T2."CHANGEDATE",
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1."WONUM" ORDER BY "CHANGEDATE" desc) as rn
      FROM TBL1 T1
      JOIN TBL2 T2 
        on T1."WONUM" = T2."WONUM"
    ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| WONUM | STATUS_T1 | STATUS_T2 |                CHANGEDATE | RN |
|-------|-----------|-----------|---------------------------|----|
|     1 |   textABC |     text3 | October, 31 2001 00:00:00 |  1 |
|     2 |   textDEF |     text3 | October, 31 2001 00:00:00 |  1 |
|     3 |   textGHI |     text3 | October, 01 2001 00:00:00 |  1 |
|     4 |   textJKL |     text3 | October, 31 2001 00:00:00 |  1 |
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked although I had to replace select * with the actual named variables.